# initWithNibName Not working as expected

Tags: iphone, ios, controller, modal-dialog, nib

I am positive that I have missed something simple here.  I am attempting to load up a sub-view (modal view) as a separate controller in iOS.  I have created a NIB file with a window that is pointing to my controller's view, the File's Owner class is set to my controller class, and I am attempting to call initWithNibName with the name of the nib file, but when I attempt to show it, it simply shows a blank view instead of the view I have build in the NIB file.  Can it not be a window in the NIB if it is a modal sub controller?  Or is there something else really obvious that I have missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to ensure that the file owner's (which must be a `UIViewController` subclass) view property in your custom xib is set appropriately. If it is not, you'll get what you describe. I know this is what you say you are doing but I am highly skeptical. It's either that, or you are not linking the right view to the `view` outlet of the file owner. When in doubt, disconnect and reconnect.

Comment: So, should it be the Window that is connected in the view?  I can tell you I am using the right controller class because other outlets I have defined show up on it.

Comment: The `view` property should be connected to the view that is to be displayed. If that is a window, then fine, it's a window, but it has to be a `UIView` of some sort.

Comment: As an addendum, the `view` property is named exactly that, `view`. If you are thinking you can set a `myVIew` outlet up to load when the view loads, then you'd be wrong.

Comment: I changed the base system to a UIView rather than a UIWindow and that fixed it - thanks for the hint.  Got me on the right track.

Comment: Yes - it is set to the view property.